# Implementing the addition operator on a generic trait

Tags: rust

I have the following generic trait and struct:

```
pub trait Parameter<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> T;
}

// Struct to add parameters of the same addable type.
pub struct ParameterAdd<T: Add> {
    first_parameter: Box<dyn Parameter<T>>,
    second_parameter: Box<dyn Parameter<T>>,
}
impl<T: Add<Output = T>> Parameter<T> for ParameterAdd<T> {
    fn get(&self) -> T {
        return self.first_parameter.get() + self.second_parameter.get();
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a public API for adding together 2 objects which implement the Parameter trait, such that calling `get()` on the sum returns the sum of the respective `get()` methods, what is the idiomatic way to go about this?

Comment: Besides the explicit `return`, there's nothing wrong with the code you have. Are you trying to avoid dynamic dispatch?

Comment: Maybe you can show the code you are not satisfied with in a small example.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `std::ops::Add` as follows has given me my desired result.

```
impl<T: Add<Output = T>> Add for Box<dyn Parameter<T>> {
    type Output = ParameterAdd<T>;
 
    fn add(self, other: Self) -> ParameterAdd<T> {
        ParameterAdd{
            first_parameter: self,
            second_parameter: other,
        }
    }
}
```

With this implementation, I can add together `Parameter<T>`s given that is addable.